# Why is the line-neutral fault current 1.5x higher than the line-line fault current?

Tags: current, transformer, short-circuit, math, fault

My commercial wiring textbook and several documents discussing fault current calculations stated "The L-N fault current is higher than the L-L fault current at the secondary terminals of a single-phase center-tapped transformer." Specifically, the l-n short circuit current is stated to vary theoretically from 1.33 to 1.67 times the line to line current.

Example given, [this](https://www.hollandindustrial.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/197/2015/12/Bussman-System-available-fault-currents.pdf) document.

Intuitively, why is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main factors limiting the available fault current:

- Impedance of the secondary winding (assuming a dead short right across the terminals). Twice as many turns of the same wire mean both the voltage and the resistance get doubled, so the fault current should remain the same.
- Power delivery/transfer capabilities of the primary winding and transformer core. Assuming the primary can deliver a given maximum power no matter what is happening on the secondary, the L-N short current could be up to twice the L-L current (which has twice the voltage for the same power).

Combining these two contributions, you could expect the L-N fault current to be somewhere between the same and twice the L-L current. However, transformer windings aren't just resistors. Inductive reactance grows faster than linearly with the number of turns, so if you take that into account, you'll end up with the theoretical limits in your question.